# C# - UWP AppInfo throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, uwp

I'm developing a C# WinForms app, using the UWP API. I'm attempting to read notifications programatically, and I have succeeded so far. However, whenever I call AppInfo from the UserNotification class, I get a NotImplementedException, no matter what property I read from AppInfo.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have only been able to find 1 answer to this question and it's not very useful, and also a few years old. This is a **major** roadblock in my project, any help is massively appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's my code.

```
        try {
            this.source = notification.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;
        } catch(NotImplementedException e) {
            this.source = "Unspecified";
        }

        NotificationBinding binding = notification.Notification.Visual.GetBinding(KnownNotificationBindings.ToastGeneric);
        if (binding != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(binding.GetTextElements()[1]);
            this.title = binding.GetTextElements().FirstOrDefault()?.Text;
            this.body = string.Join("\n", binding.GetTextElements().Skip(1).Select(t => t.Text));
        }
        Init();
```

I'm using the code from [the examples in the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener)

Comment: Please post your code. Most likely you need to replace the line that contains `NotImplementedException` with some actual code (or comment it out).

Comment: Like I said, I'm using the UWP API. It reads the notification just fine, I'm not sure how I would go about doing anything about the exception when it's not caused by my code specifically.

Answer (score 1):

> UWP AppInfo throws NotImplementedException

Based on the exception message, it looks like `notification.AppInfo.DisplayInfo` has not
been implemented for WinForm platform. For this scenario, we have a workaround for getting AppInfo with [AppDiagnosticInfo][1] api. Please refer the following code

```
var list = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync();
var currentPackage = list.Where(o => o.AppInfo.PackageFamilyName == Package.Current.Id.FamilyName).FirstOrDefault();
if (currentPackage != null)
{
    AppInfo currentAppInfo = currentPackage.AppInfo;
    var display = currentAppInfo.DisplayInfo;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this get the display name of my program? That's not what I'm trying to do, I'm sorry if I didn't explain thoroughly enough.
I need the name of the program that sends any notification. This would include Google Chrome, The Snipping Tool, Windows Defender.

I'm using a Notification Listener in order to catch any and all notifications, and it works perfectly except for the AppInfo property of the UserNotification.

Comment: Are you using [UserNotificationListener Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener?view=winrt-19041)? If it is, that might be the reason because the UserNotificationListener Class is not supported to use in not-UWP apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private async Task<AppDisplayInfo> GetDisplayInfo()
    {
        var list = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync();
        
        var currentPackage = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppInfo.PackageFamilyName == Package.Current.Id.FamilyName);
        if (currentPackage != null)
        {
            var currentAppInfo = currentPackage.AppInfo;
            var display = currentAppInfo.DisplayInfo;

            return display;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I just took Roy's answer and wrapped it in an operation to return the display info - works just fine.